# DQL relation Many to Many with Symfony

Tags: sql, dql, symfony5

I would like to SELECT the categories in my table product_category through the table categories.

I have a FK many to many between product and category so the table product_category has been created dynamically.

I found that code for get the information in the other table when the FK is not directly in the table I am :

```
->join(ProductComponentSupplier::class, "pcs", \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, "p.id = pcs.product")
```

But in this case, ProductComponentSupplier is a class so it's accessible that way.

I would like to know if there is a way in DQL to get the information or I have to use SQL.

In SQL would be :

```
SELECT * 
FROM category 
LEFT JOIN product_category ON category.id = product_category.category_id
```

I hope I was clear.
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Doctrine knows about the juction table, you should be able to do something like
->select('p')
->from(Product::class,'p')
->leftJoin('p.categories','c')

Comment: I was probably tired... should work in fact. Thx ;)